# modifying shared.html in atk4

Tags: atk4

Just learning atk4. (4.2.4, I believe. Installed through `curl -sS http://agiletoolkit.org/install | sh`)

How do I modify and load shared.html in atk4? I can only edit atk4/templates/shared/shared.html?

I tried copying shared.html to the following locations and edit them:

```
/templates/default/shared.html
/templates/default/shared/shared.html
/templates/shared/shared.html
```

and none seems to be loaded at all.

Comment: the good way to find is to change default template from shared.html to shaaaaared.html (non-existantfile), and then look into exceptions, which locations were attempted.

Answer (score 0):

It should work at least from `/templates/shared/shared.html`.

Please try to use latest ATK4 version from master branch from GitHub https://github.com/atk4/atk4. Current fully working version is 4.2.5.

If you start to learn ATK4 or start completely new project based on ATK4 framework, then you better look into 4.3 branch in GitHub and learn and use it. There are quite a lot of things changed in 4.3 (not yet released) version so you better use them now and you'll not need to "convert" your project from 4.2.x to 4.3 later on when 4.3 will be officially released.

Comment: Thanx for the reply. I tried 4.3, but couldn't figure out how to install correctly. Cloned the 4.3 github repo and perform composer install produces error: "Invalid version string "4.3.x". Are there other instructions? I couldn't find one.

Comment: And I still can't get /templates/shared/shared.html to load. The composer.json states version as "atk4/atk4": "dev-master". Is that 4.2.5?

Comment: Also, are there any documentation for 4.3? I can't seem to find anything solid.

Comment: Master branch in GitHub is on 4.2.5 version and it's fully working. Probably there are some issues with PathFinder in your Frontend class in /lib folder. Can you post some of your code here for reference?

Comment: Not sure about documentation of 4.3. Maybe Romans (author of framework) will take a look on this post some day soon. I know some docs exist, but not sure how complete they are. I'm still working on stable 4.2.5 version and couldn't understand how to install fresh 4.3 myself :)

Comment: 4.3 is not yet released. I'm working hard on it. Use on your own risk ;)